passing a custom camera view to gpencil mesh convert
I am trying to learn how to use the Python API for Blender, and have been wanting to see if I can make some kind of gpencil to mesh convert tool to see if i can make it do consistent conversions through a specific camera view.
I was able to come up with this so far based on what I could find across various searches:
import bpy


def get_3d_view_custom_context():
    """creates a 3d view custom context

    Args:
        None

    Returns:
        custom_context (dict): the dictionary creating a custom context
    """
    my_camera = bpy.context.scene.cameraComboBox
    print('my_camera', my_camera)
    if my_camera == 'no_items':
        return

    custom_context = bpy.context.copy()

    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == "WINDOW":
                    custom_context["area"] = area
                    # view_3d = area.spaces.active
                    # area.spaces.active.local_view = bpy.context.scene.objects[my_camera]
                    # view_3d.camera_to_view()
                    custom_context["region"] = region
                    break
            break
    # bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[my_camera]
    # areas3d  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
    # bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view({'area':areas3d[0]})
    print("Custom context use with VIEW_3D area and WINDOW region.")
    custom_context['scene'].camera = bpy.context.scene.objects[my_camera]
    # bpy.ops.view_3d.camera_to_view()
    custom_context['space_data'].region_3d.view_perspective == 'CAMERA'
    return custom_context



class ConvertToMeshFunc(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Convert gpencil to geo"""

    bl_idname = "gpencil.blendlines_meshify"
    bl_label = "Convert to Poly"
    bl_context = "gpencil"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.object
        override = get_3d_view_custom_context()
        bpy.ops.object.gpencil_modifier_apply(modifier="Noise")
        obj_world_scale = obj.matrix_world.to_scale()
        depth = 0.005 * obj.data.pixel_factor * min(obj_world_scale)
        resolution = 12

        bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type="POLY",use_timing_data=False)
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target="MESH")
        active = context.view_layer.objects.active
        selected = context.view_layer.objects.selected
        # objs = [item for item in selected if item != active]
        # converted = objs[0]
        # print("{} converted to {}.".format(obj.name, converted.name))
        return {"FINISHED"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {"OBJECT"}

class GPencilToMesh(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Convert gpencil to mesh, cap the ends, cut out gpmask, add material/stroke attributes"""

    bl_idname = "object.mesh_check"
    bl_label = "GPencil to Mesh"
    bl_context = "object"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.gpencil.blendlines_meshify()
        return {"FINISHED"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode in {"OBJECT"}

class UpdateCamerasList(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.greasepencil_camsrefresh"
    bl_label = "Refresh Cameras"
    bl_context = "object"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        cams_list = [ob for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects if ob.type == 'CAMERA']
        cams_combo_items = []
        if cams_list:
            for idx, cam in enumerate(cams_list):
                cams_combo_items.append((cam.name, cam.name, "", idx+1))
            self.updateCameraDropdown(cams_combo_items)
        print('cams_combo_items:', cams_combo_items)

        return {'FINISHED'}

    @classmethod
    def updateCameraDropdown(cls, cItems=None):
        if not cItems:
            cItems = [
                ("no_items", "No items", "", 1),
            ]
            # cItems = [(bpy.data.objects['Camera'], 'Camera', '', 1)]
            default_selection = "no_items"
        else:
            default_selection = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].camera.name
        bpy.types.Scene.cameraComboBox = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
                                            items=cItems,
                                            name="Cameras",
                                            description="Camera",
                                            default=default_selection,
                                        )
        # print('get_3d_view_custom_context():', get_3d_view_custom_context())
        # my_camera = bpy.context.scene.cameraComboBox
        # bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[my_camera]
        # areas3d  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
        # bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view({'area':areas3d[0]})
        get_3d_view_custom_context()


class VIEW3D_PT_greasepencil_mesh_test(bpy.types.Panel):
    """BlendLines Export UI Panel"""

    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_greasepencil_mesh_test"
    bl_category = "GREASEPENCILTEST"
    bl_label = "testing meshify for greasepencil"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        box = layout.box()
        row = box.row()
        row.operator(
            "object.mesh_check",
            text="Mesh Check",
            icon="MESH_ICOSPHERE",
        )
        box1 = layout.box()
        row1 = box1.row()
        row1.label(text="Set Camera:")
        row2 = box1.row()
        row2.prop(scene, "cameraComboBox", text="")
        row3 = box1.row()
        row3.operator(
            "object.greasepencil_camsrefresh",
            text="Refresh Cameras",
            )


# Registration
# =========================================================================
classes = (
    ConvertToMeshFunc,
    GPencilToMesh,
    UpdateCamerasList,
    VIEW3D_PT_greasepencil_mesh_test,
)


def register():
    UpdateCamerasList.updateCameraDropdown()
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        if cls.is_registered:
            bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.cameraComboBox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

this seems to just create a mesh based on the current viewport I am looking through which is great, but what I really want to do is pass a view from a specific camera somewhere in bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type="POLY",use_timing_data=False), but when I pass the result of get_3d_view_custom_context() this errors out.
I am still having troubles understanding what this "context" stuff is so I am pretty stuck as of now. Would someone be able to provide some insight as to how to make sure this mesh conversion ONLY WORKS from a specific camera view...?
